# Uploading Excel using IOFactory & converting into HTML

Tags: php, html, import-from-excel

I am using IOFactory to read uploaded Excel using PHP Code. There are some links & images url in excel rows & columns. My requirement is that once excel is uploaded it should converted HTML and render the HTML code insert the excel?

Can this be done in PHP? I was successful in converting the excel to HTML but it's not rendering the data of HTML in html format.

Comment: its showing as excel sheet into html, i need to have html code rendering while converting

Comment: hello,
is there any way to copy the excel data to html & render that html using IOFactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used another library for converting Excel to HTML, library name is Reader Excel.

Appreciate the help & replies

Answer (score -1):

based on my experience for dealing with Excel in PHP, I can suggest you to use [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com), here is a HelloWorld Example:

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel */
include 'PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set properties
echo date('H:i:s') . " Set properties\n";
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.");


// Add some data
echo date('H:i:s') . " Add some data\n";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Rename sheet
echo date('H:i:s') . " Rename sheet\n";
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";
```

Comment: He is talking about upload.